# How can I redownload an episode of podcast that I accidentally deleted?

Tags: itunes

I have accidentally deleted a file of an episode in iTunes podcast. Now whenever I try to play it, I get an error message asking me to locate the file on disk.

[image: error]

I don't have it anymore, and I can't figure out how to tell iTunes to download it again.

Another problem is, that if I delete the episode via right click -> delete, I can't get it to show up in the list again, or even download it.

Is there any simple way to tell iTunes to get the list of episodes again and redownload the ones that aren't available anymore?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in "album" view, there should still be an "album" placeholder for your podcast, even if you do not have any more episodes stored locally in your computer. Right click (or Command click) on the podcast's album/icon and then select the option "Show All Available Episodes". This re-downloads the entire list of episodes in the podcast's RSS feed.

Is important to note that "Show All Available Episodes" does not re-download the episodes themselves, but rather *the list of episodes*. This is the same list that anybody sees in iTunes if they haven't subscribed to the podcast yet. You will be able to select and re-download individual episodes from that list that you have already downloaded and deleted. Hope this helps.

Comment: Note this no longer works in iTunes 11+

Answer (score 2):

For iTunes 11+ delete the episodes as described above then select the `...` icon on the top right of the screen and choose Refresh.  Deleted episodes will re-appear in the feed tab and you can re-download them.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click the episode with **!** → Show in iTunes Store

The episode will show up in the store with a "Get" button to the right.
That should let you download it.

iTunes is really weird.