# How can I get iTunes to redownload a deleted Podcast item?

Tags: itunes, podcasts

This question is pretty much the same as [How can I redownload an episode of podcast which I accidentaly deleted?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27373/how-can-i-redownload-an-episode-of-podcast-which-i-accidentaly-deleted). That old question had an answer,  although a comment says the answer is no longer relevant to later versions of iTunes. I'm not sure what the protocol is for this situation, but since I have the same problem today I thought I'd re-ask the question.

I am running iTunes v11.1.4.62 on Windows 7. I needed to reclaim some disk space so I manually deleted some of the downloaded podcast files from the iTunes folders.

How can I redownload that file via iTunes when I wish to listen to it again? The Podcast listing indicates that that file is already downloaded (i.e. there is no cloud icon to click on to initiate a download)

Answer (score 1):

Press the three dots right next to the name when you select the Podcast row. Select (-) Delete. That will delete the row.

Then on the main Podcast, right-click and select "Refresh podcast". The row will re-appear with a little cloud next to it.

If the publisher has deleted the Podcast from their library, I guess you cannot recover it.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to let iTunes delete the podcast for you.
There should be three dots behind the podcast-name -> click on them -> delete download.
Probably it then will recognize that the podcast is already missing or deinstall it properly.

Comment: I cannot see an option like this. I can right click and choose to Delete, but that also deletes the entry from the podcast listing altogether. I cannot then redownload it later as it's totally removed from the list.

Comment: Yes you can, search for it in the iTunes Podcast library or click on "show in iTunes store"